# Hibernate TransientPropertyValueException When saving data

Tags: java, hibernate, hbmxml

I am trying to insert data to the DB using hibernate . Here is how I going perform that action

```
    session.beginTransaction();
    pojo.StuDetails stu = new StuDetails();
    stu.setFName(f_name);
    stu.setLName(l_name);
    stu.setSex(sex);
    stu.setDob(dob);

    pojo.Subject sub = new Subject(subject, day, time);
    pojo.SubjectHasStuDetails shs = new SubjectHasStuDetails(stu, sub);

    session.save(shs);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

But It gives me an error saying

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property
>   references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before
>   current operation

Here is my student details entity

```
 public class StuDetails  implements java.io.Serializable {


 private Integer id;
 private String FName;
 private String LName;
 private String sex;
 private String dob;
 private Set subjectHasStuDetailses = new HashSet();
 ...
 //constructors and getters, setters
```

My StudentDetails hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="pojo.StuDetails" table="stu_details" catalog="laravel_test" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="FName" type="string">
            <column name="f_name" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="LName" type="string">
            <column name="l_name" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="sex" type="string">
            <column name="sex" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="dob" type="string">
            <column name="dob" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="subjectHasStuDetailses" table="subject_has_stu_details" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="stu_details_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="pojo.SubjectHasStuDetails" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My Subject Entity looks like

```
 public class Subject  implements java.io.Serializable {


 private Integer id;
 private String subName;
 private String day;
 private String time;
 private Set subjectHasStuDetailses = new HashSet();

 ...
 //constructors and getters, setters
```

Subject.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="pojo.Subject" table="subject" catalog="laravel_test" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="subName" type="string">
            <column name="sub_name" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="day" type="string">
            <column name="day" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="time" type="string">
            <column name="time" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="subjectHasStuDetailses" table="subject_has_stu_details" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="subject_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="pojo.SubjectHasStuDetails" />
        </set>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Here is the SubjetcHasStuDetails Entity

```
 public class SubjectHasStuDetails  implements java.io.Serializable {


 private Integer id;
 private StuDetails stuDetails;
 private Subject subject;
 ...
 //constructors and getters, setters
```

SubjectHasStuDetials.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="pojo.SubjectHasStuDetails" table="subject_has_stu_details" 
           catalog="laravel_test" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="stuDetails" class="pojo.StuDetails" fetch="select">
            <column name="stu_details_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="subject" class="pojo.Subject" fetch="select" >
            <column name="subject_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Can someone help me on this error please ... Thanks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In your** `SubjectHasStuDetials.hbm.xml` **make these changes :**

```
<many-to-one name="stuDetails" class="pojo.StuDetails" fetch="select" cascade="all">
            <column name="stu_details_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
<many-to-one name="subject" class="pojo.Subject" fetch="select" cascade="all" >
            <column name="subject_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
```

Add **`cascade="all"`** attribute to both `stuDetails` and `subject` many-to-one tags.

- **Cascade attribute** is mandatory, when ever we apply relationship
  between objects, cascade attribute transfers operations done on one
  object onto its related child objects
- If we write `cascade = “all”` then changes at parent class object will
  be effected to child class object too,  if we write cascade = “all”
  then all operations like insert, delete, update at parent object will
  be effected to child object also.
- Example: if we apply insert(or update or delete) operation on parent
  class object, then child class objects will also be stored into the
  database.

Comment: Yes. It worked. Thank you so much. But I have a question. Why cascade="all" only in  SubjectHasStuDetials.hbm.xml ???