# Spring JPA ManyToOne - Save the transient instance before flushing

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I created a `Spring Web Application` with database access. I have a class `Person` - which has references to a class `Address`. A person has an address as well as the company, so `person` and `company` both refer to the `Address` table. I did this by defining a `@ManyToOne` relation from person to address as well as the company.

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name="COMPANY_ID")
    private Adress companyId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name="SUBSIDIARY_ID")
    private Adress subsidiaryId;
```

In the person repository I have a save method like this:

```
 public Person save(Person entity) {

    SaveAccess<Person> ao = createSaveAccess();

    ao.setEntity(entity);
    ao.execute();
    return ao.getResult();
}
```

The thing is, if I try to add a new person I get a `Hibernate-TransientPropertyValueException` which says `Object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing.` Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

    @JoinColumn (name="COMPANY_ID")
    private Adress companyId;

   @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn (name="SUBSIDIARY_ID")
    private Adress subsidiaryId;
```

reference:
[Hibernate TransientPropertyValueException When saving data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872396/hibernate-transientpropertyvalueexception-when-saving-data)

https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-many-to-one-using-annotations-1.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is, now it works if companyId and subsidiaryId are different and not in the database. But if the subsidiaryId and companyId are the same or one of them is in the database I get a UniqueConstraint Violated exception.

Comment: Do I have to make a bidirectional association here? Something like a OneToMany Mapping in address? Like that:
 `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID")
private Set<Person> person_companies;
 
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "SUBSIDIARY_ID")
private Set<Person> person_subsidiaries;`

Comment: Did you find a solution how to update company and subsidiary when they're already stored in DB?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a `@OneToOne` annotation of a table called `Product` to another one called `Category`. I wanted to specify that every `Product` has to have a single `Category`.

Thus, I had to make sure to set the cascade type to be `CascadeType.ALL` like so:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_NAME")
private Category category;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so the address contains so much data it justifiable to store as an independent entity. For performance considerations I recommend you to use embeddable + embedded classes for this purpose:

```
@Embeddable
public class Address
{
  String number;
  String street;
  String city;
  String country;
}

@Entity
public class Person
{
  @Id
  protected long id
  ...
  @Embedded
  Address address;
  @Embedded
  Address companyAddress;
  ...
}
```

If you have a legacy system and you have to store the addresses in a separate table, there is the @SecondaryTable solution:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
@SecondaryTable(name = "ADDRESS", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID"))
public class Employee
{
    //...
    @Column(table = "ADDRESS")
    private Address address;

    @Column(table = "ADDRESS")
    private Address companyAddress;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunally I am not able to do this, since it's a requirement to store Addresses in a seperate table in the database. It's because we need addresses not only for people but also for other entities.

Comment: In this case you can apply the @SecondaryTable solution. I have modified my answer.

Comment: The thing is, I need to have a Entity Address too because I have a rest service, that returns them.