# How fix org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

this is my error:

Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

I added Cascade.ALL to ManyToOne but i have same problem.

Comment: Check this ..it may help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872396/hibernate-transientpropertyvalueexception-when-saving-data

Comment: Nothing to do, same mistake

Comment: i think you need to post more details about problem

Comment: Can you post your `Entity` as well, otherwise it is hard to figure out the mistake

Comment: Thanks guys, in the end I solved by inserting cascade = all in the correct entity